# C# Linq to XML - simple query returns no results

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this XML which contains a list of entities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Connections>
  <Connection>
    <ConnectionName>connName</ConnectionName>
    <InterfaceName>Account Lookup</InterfaceName>
    <RequestFolder>C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Requests</RequestFolder>
    <ResponseFolder>C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Responses</ResponseFolder>
  </Connection>
</Connections>
```

I'm trying to retrive one of them based on its name and build an object from it.

```
var results = (from i in this.Elements("Connection")
                           where i.Element("ConnectionName").ToString() == stubConnectionName
                           select new {
                               interfaceName = ((string)i.Element("InterfaceName").Value),
                               requestFolder = ((string)i.Element("RequestFolder").Value),
                               responseFolder = ((string)i.Element("ResponseFolder").Value),
                           }).Single();

return new StubConnection(stubConnectionName, results.interfaceName, results.requestFolder, results.responseFolder);
```

The problem is that results comes back empty. What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
where i.Element("ConnectionName").ToString() == stubConnectionName
```

has to be:

```
where i.Element("ConnectionName").Value == stubConnectionName
```

because [`XElement.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) returns `<ConnectionName>connName</ConnectionName>` including the XML tags, while [`XElement.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx) only returns the enclosed connection name without the tags.

By the way, you are unnecessarily casting all the values (which are already of type `string`) to `string`. You can simplify that:

```
var results = (from i in this.Elements("Connection")
               where i.Element("ConnectionName").Value == stubConnectionName
               select new
               {
                   interfaceName = i.Element("InterfaceName").Value,
                   requestFolder = i.Element("RequestFolder").Value,
                   responseFolder = i.Element("ResponseFolder").Value,
               }).Single();
```

You could even go one step further and directly select and return your result, without using an anonymous type in between:

```
return (from i in this.Elements("Connection")
        where i.Element("ConnectionName").Value == stubConnectionName
        select new StubConnection(stubConnectionName,
                                  i.Element("InterfaceName").Value,
                                  i.Element("RequestFolder").Value,
                                  i.Element("ResponseFolder").Value)).Single();
```

---

Please also understand the differences of

### `XElement.Value` *vs* `(string)XElement`

Be careful when calling the Value property directly, as it will throw an Exception if the element contains no value.  [Cast the element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263) *(not the `Value`, but the `XElement` directly)* to string if you are not sure whether it will contain a value. If it doesn't, null will be returned; otherwise, the result is the same.